# single quotes replaced by &#039; while trying to update data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm a bit new here in codeigniter. Here i'm facing the problem while trying to update the data. When inserting the data containng single quotes for example "latest's" there is no problem but while trying to update the data, the single quotes is replaced with special characters inside the textbox like this

[image].

Thanks in advance for any sort of help.

---

My input code for update looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo form_input([
    'name'=>'pname', 
    'class'=>'form-control', 
    'placeholder'=>'Product Name', 
    'value'=> set_value('pname', $product->pname)
]);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using set_value() or html_escape() or what? Show some code.

Comment: i'm using the set_value. i've posted the image and the code as well. Thanks

Comment: How did you insert the data? Check your actual database values to see if they are `"latest's"` or `"latest&amp;039;s"`

Comment: Please show your validation rule set for pname. I have a feeling you are double encoding the HTML entities. set_value() does this, and if you have a validation rule that's doing it, you're double encoding, and that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you, for your help @BrianGottier, i removed the set_value() and it worked. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

OK - check to make sure "pname" is actually the name of the form item.  Mine wasn't - i fixed it and its fine now. ;)